# "missing } after property list" at function FB.subclass of all.js file

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to create an application on Facebook, after doing like the tutorial from FB Developer site. I got the error at the step using Javascript SKD, I try to get this function, and it's really incorrect.

[image: Error when using Javascript SDK]

---

Let me show more about my application:

#### Here is my settings:

```
Summary             
App ID/API Key                              App Secret
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Canvas Page                                 Canvas URL
https://apps.facebook.com/ibattleship/      http://192.168.11.154:8091/

Secure Canvas URL                           Canvas FBML/iframe
https://192.168.11.154/                     iframe 

Contact Email                               Support Email
xxxxxxx@gmail.com                           xxxxxx@gmail.com
```

#### And index.php file:

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<?php echo APP_ID ?>', // App ID
            channelURL : '//192.168.11.154:8091/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });     
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
    // Additional initialization code here  
</script>
Hello, world.
</body>
</html>
```

#### And the `channel.html` file

```
<?php
  $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$cache_expire);
  header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire).' GMT');
?>

<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

But, when I run this page, I got the above error. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug from Facebook Javascript SDK.